# Is cancelAllLocalNotifications App specific or for all local notifications

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications

I'm working a bit with local notifications for the iPhone. All well so far and I'm just seeking confirmation about the cancelAllLocalNotifications.

Would it be correct that firing off a cancelAllLocalNotifications would cancel all SCHEDULED notifications ONLY FOR THIS APP?

E.g other (non scheduled) notifications in this app would still work and scheduled notifications in other apps would still remain. My logical mind say it should be so, just want to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All calls to the local notifications API are restricted to the subset of notifications that your app has created.

Answer (score 1):

cancelAllNotification cancel first 64 notification of the system scheduled by application.

Comment: Where is this documented? What should I do to remove all of them?